# Get ClaimsPrincipal/Identity from AzureAD secured powershell core Azure Function

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, powershell-core

I have a Azure Function developed using Powershell Core 6 and secured by enabling the Azure AD Authentication. If an anonymous request is made by doing a GET through a browser, the user is redirected to Azure AD login first and then redirected to my Azure Function.
[image: Authentication Configuration]

Now, in the Powershell function, I need to know which has user logged in which is usually found in the `ClaimsPrincipal` as indicated here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=csharp

But the `httpRequest.Context.User` is null when I access it through powershell. Below is the code in my Function:

```
using namespace System.Net

# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)

$body = @{
    Context = $Request.Context;
    HttpContext = $Request.HTTP.Context;
    Request = $Request;
}

# Associate values to output bindings by calling 'Push-OutputBinding'.
Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
    StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
    Body = $body
})
```

It basically returns everything in an attempt to find the `User's Identity`

Where can I find the User's Identity?

I don;t want to use these headers because they can easily be manipulated to still make the API work.

```
$Request.Headers['X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-NAME']
$Request.Headers['X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-ID']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data you are looking for should be under $Request.Headers, for example:

```
$Request.Headers['X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-NAME']
$Request.Headers['X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-ID']
```

The `$Request` object structure in PowerShell Functions is different from C# Functions. Specifically, it does not have neither `Context` nor `HTTP` property, this is why you are getting nulls. In order to see the entire content, trace something like:

```
$Request | ConvertTo-Json
```

Comment: Thanks, but these headers can be easily manipulated. I could change them and still use the same cookie/accesstoken to make the API call succesfully. Is there a way to get the claims using access_token itself?

Comment: Manipulating these headers may not be that easy. These headers are injected by the App Service platform, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-how-to#access-user-claims for more details.

Comment: Did detailed research over the weekend. Yes, I can safely use these headers now. Thanks! Here is my client: https://github.com/pdhimate/AzureAD-Client